# Anomaly Detection Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, filter, filtering, heuristics

I am tasked with detecting anomalies (known or unknown) using  machine-learning algorithms from data in various formats - e.g. emails, IMs etc.

1. What are your favorite and most effective anomaly detection algorithms?
2. What are their limitations and sweet-spots?
3. How would you recommend those limitations be addressed?

All suggestions very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statistical filters like [Bayesian filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering) or some bastardised version employed by some spam filters are easy to implement. Plus there are lots of online documentation about it.

The big downside is that it cannot really detect unknown things. You train it with a large sample of known data so that it can categorize new incoming data. But you can turn the traditional spam filter upside down: train it to recognize legitimate data instead of illegitimate data so that anything it doesn't recognize is an anomaly.

Comment: Thanks, Bayesian spam filters seems a decent approach. I was wondering if you have tried Kalman Filters, SVMs, or other approaches.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you'd apply a Kalman Filter to text processing. Maybe on a byte-by-byte basis but that would be too fine grained to be as effective to statistical analysis of words and/or phrases.

Comment: @slebetman Which algorithm or technique will work good or atleast satisfactory in case of real-time transaction systems? We need to deal with input records having many parameters and detect an anomaly while processing itself such that the system doesn't hang or slow down.

Answer (score 3):

There are various types of anomaly detection algorithms, depending on the type of data and the problem you are trying to solve:

1. Anomalies in time series signals: 
   Time series signals is anything you can draw as a line graph over time (e.g., CPU utilization, temperature, rate per minute of number of emails, rate of visitors on a webpage, etc).  Example algorithms are Holt-Winters, ARIMA models, Markov Models, and more. I gave a talk on this subject a few months ago - it might give you more ideas about algorithms and their limitations.
   The video is at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrOM2z6h_RQ
2. Anomalies in Tabular data: These are cases where you have feature vector that describe something (e.g, transforming an email to a feature vector that describes it: number of recipients, number of words, number of capitalized words, counts of keywords, etc....). Given a large set of such feature vectors, you want to detect some that are anomalies compared to the rest (sometimes called "outlier detection"). Almost any clustering algorithm is suitable in these cases, but which one would be most suitable depends on the type of features and their behavior -- real valued features, ordinal, nominal or anything other. The type of features determine if certain distance functions are suitable (the basic requirement for most clustering algorithms), and some algorithms are better with certain types of features than others.
   The simplest algo to try is k-means clustering, where an anomaly sample would be either very small clusters or vectors that are far from all cluster centers. One sided SVM can also detect outliers, and has the flexibility of choosing different kernels (and effectively different distance functions). Another popular algo is DBSCAN.
3. When anomalies are known, the problem becomes a supervised learning problem, so you can use classification algorithms and train them on the known anomalies examples. However, as mentioned - it would only detect those known anomalies and if the number of training samples for anomalies is very small, the trained classifiers may not be accurate. Also, because the number of anomalies is typically very small compared to "no-anomalies", when training the classifiers you might want to use techniques like boosting/bagging, with over sampling of the anomalies class(es), but optimize on very small False Positive rate. There are various techniques to do it in the literature --- one idea that I found to work many times very well is what Viola-Jones used for face detection - a cascade of classifiers. see: http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/EE148-2005-Spring/pprs/viola04ijcv.pdf

(DISCLAIMER: I am the chief data scientist for Anodot, a commercial company doing real time anomaly detection for time series data).